# Counting the number of ways to paint the houses

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $n$ houses on a street numbered $h_1,h_2,h_3\dots h_n$. Each house can either be painted blue or red.

$(i)$. How many ways can the houses $h_1,h_2,h_3\dots h_n$ be painted?

$(ii)$. Suppose $n\ge4$ and the houses are situated on $n$ points on a circle. There is an additional constraint on painting the houses: Exactly two houses need to be painted blue and they cannot be next to each other. How many ways can the houses $h_1,h_2,h_3\dots h_n$ be painted under this new constraint?

$(iii)$. How will your answer to the previous question change if the houses are located on $n$ points on a line.

The answer to the $(i)$ is $2^n$. I am confused with $(ii)$ and $(iii)$.

Comment: **Hint:** How many way are there to *choose* two out of $n$ houses to be blue (ignoring the cannont-be-next-to-each-other constraint)? How many ways are there to pick the blue houses such that the cannont-be-next-to-each-other constraint is violated?

Comment: Are the $h_1, h_2, h_3,...h_n$ houses *serially* located (in a row/circle) or *randomly* arranged ?

Comment: @xyz did any of answers help you ?

Comment: @trueblueanil in the ii part they are located on a circle and in the iii part on line

Comment: What I am asking is: if in a line/circle, do the houses have to be in order $h_1,h_2, h_3, h_4...$ or can they be, say, $h_1, h_4, h_3, h_2...$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ii-) If only two houses will be painted blue , we can choose them by $C(n,2)$ different ways. Then , we have $n-2$ red houses. We can place them on a circle by $((n-2)-1)=(n-3)!$ ways.

Now ,we also have $(n-2)$ gaps between each of red houses in circle that are suitable for blue houses to make them separate . We can choose $C(n-2,2)$ different place for blues but they can interchange in these two places ,so multiply by $2$!.(Or, just say $P(n-2,2)$)

Result : $C(n,2) \times (n-3)! \times C(n-2,2) \times 2!$

iii-) If they are line choose blues by $C(n,2)$. Moreover , align the left by $(n-2)!$. Now , the red houses have made $(n-2)+1$ possible place to set blue houses separately. Then choose 2 places for them by $C(n-1,2)$ but they can interchange in these two places ,so multiply by $2!$ .(Or just say $P(n-1,2)$)

Result: $C(n,2) \times (n-2)! \times C(n-1,2)  \times 2!$

Comment: can you explain how do we have (n-3) gaps between each of red houses?

Comment: @xyz thanks for warnig , it was very critical typo. Because of there are $(n-2)$ red houses ,there are $(n-2)$ gaps among them. You can imagine it like side of polygones. If it is square there are $4$ points and $4$ side etc.